# What does return function do here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

i'm a noob and completed the 8.9 and 8.10 perfectly fine of the following exercise but couldn't understand how 8.11 worked because of the Return Value. what happens exactly at line 23 with our return value?

My interpretation is that `"The Great"` was added to `great_magicians` list at line 17 then at 21 it goes back into our empty `magicians` list by assigning it the variable at line 29 `great_magicians`? am i thinking about this correctly?

```
def show_magicians(magicians):
    """Prints the name of each magician"""
    for magician in magicians:
        print(magician)



def make_great(magicians):
    """Adds "The Great" to everyones name on list"""
    # Build new list to hold the great musicians
    great_magicians = []

    # Make each magician great, and add it to great_magicians
    while magicians:
        magician = magicians.pop()
        great_magician = magician + " The Great"
        great_magicians.append(great_magician)

    # Add the great magicians back into magicians   
    for great_magician in great_magicians:
        magicians.append(great_magician)

    return magicians

magicians = ['houdini', 'todd', 'robert', 'jenny']
show_magicians(magicians)

print("\nGreat magicians:")
great_magicians = make_great(magicians[:])
show_magicians(great_magicians)

print("\nOriginal magicians:")
show_magicians(magicians)
```

Comment: There's no point in the second `for` loop. It's just making a copy of `great_magicians`, but you can just do `return great_magicians`.

Comment: Never mind. I see that `make_great` is supposed to modify its argument in place, that's why it copies back into the original `magicians` list.

Comment: I believe the point of the exercise is to demonstrate that lists are mutable and so can be changed in place. However, if you pass a copy, the original list is left unchanged. Change your code snippet replacing `magicians[:]` with `magicians` and see how the output of your third call to `show_magicians` changes. The point is that `[:]` sends a reference to a *copy* of your list to the function, rather than a reference to the original list.

Comment: This was my first post and i'm amazed by how quick you guys responded! I don't feel so alone in this journey now and can't wait to learn more so that i can contribute soon too. It's amazing how fast you guys read code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It pretty much just returns the "updated" list of magicians, with " The Great" added to their name.

This is done in order to save it in a variable, as you do in line 29:

```
great_magicians = make_great(magicians[:])
```

make_great(magicians[:]) returns a list of magicians with " The Great" added, and you're therefore able to throw it straight into a list.

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
great_magicians = make_great(magicians[:])
```

the value returned by the function is what gets assigned to the `great_magicians` variable. If you didn't have

```
return magicians
```

at the end of the function, you would assign `None` to the variable, rather than the list of great magicians.

This is the general way that you get results out of functions. You use parameters to send values into functions, and `return` to get values out of them.